# How to find all lines of code that start and end with specified string in VScode (using Regular Expression)

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

How to find all lines of code that start and end with specified string in VScode
and replace some part of those line with other string (using Regular Expression)?

**For Example:**

**1**. Find all lines that start with `import` and end with `.ts` (with any number or chars allowed in between)

**2**. Delete only `.ts` part from all those lines

*For example:*

It should match lines like

```
import { AddToCompare } from '@Booking/core/modules/compare/AddToCompare.ts'
```

and then remove `.ts` from end from all those lines to make it

```
import { AddToCompare } from '@Booking/core/modules/compare/AddToCompare'
```

PS:
To find lines starting with `import` I used `^\s*import`
but dont know what expression to use for rest of the pattern.

Also most solutions here are for python and grep but not for vscode.

Comment: In case someone is here to find a partial match at start and end: `(= IIF)(.*)(\),)`  this finds a string that starts with  `= IIF` and ends with `),` and has anything in the middle like this example `= IIF(@Name IS NOT NULL, @Name , [NAME]),` Recomendation: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find

```
^(\s*import .*)\.ts'$
```

Replace

```
$1'
```